# how to resend email to new created user with wrong email

Tags: users

I created a new user, after several hours the email sent by the system was undelivered because the email was not correct.

After changing the email with the correct email, how can I resend the email? I could not find this.

Answer (score 1):

[`_user_mail_notify()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/_user_mail_notify/7.x) is the underlying Drupal function that does the work of sending out a user account creation email. You can reference the API doc link on how it's used, then call the function in the appropriate code context (e.g. menu callback, submission function, drush eval, etc.) for your situation.

Comment: it looks too complicated to me. Is there any gui or module to resend the email to new user.

Comment: There isn't in one core. There might be some contrib module, but I'm not familiar with one. If you're just manually managing new user accounts, I would just delete the existing account, then recreated it with the correct the email.